# Show popup when close tab in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to show a popup confermation when page reload or go outside my website in Vue js.
I just have implemented the `beforeRouteLeave` function in my component, but this works only with when I go to another page in my site, not when I go outside or I reload the page. I just already try `window.addEventListener` function but the popup appears in all my website.
I want to show up this confermation message only in the page of this Vue component

There are some example:

This is in the Vue Component:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  const answer = window.confirm('Confermation Message')
  if (answer) {
    next()
  } else {
    next(false)
  }
},
```

This is in the Vue Component, but outside the `export default`:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  if (logic) {
    event.returnValue = 'Sei sicuro di uscire? Le modifiche non salvate andranno perse'
  }
})
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```js
const confirmExit = () => window.confirm('Sei sicuro di uscire? Le modifiche non salvate andranno perse')

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', evt => {
  if (!confirmExit()) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.returnValue = true;
  }
});
```

Then in your `beforeRouteLeave` method you can also check `if (confirmExit())` instead of `if (answer)`.

Comment: Hi Vergil, the problem persists, if I reload another page the message show up, but i don't want it, I need this message only in the page of this Vue component